# setting a default value for a Symfony controller action

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

I'm attempting to learn how to use the Symfony 2.3 framework. I thought it would be a good first  exercise to modify `Acme\DemoBundle\DemoController::helloaction()` to provide a default name when none was entered.

This is the original:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

It works with urls like `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/SOMENAME` and fails with urls like `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/SOMENAME/`, `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello` and `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/`

This is what I did:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello", name="_demo_hello", defaults={"name" = "World"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    return array('name' => $name);
}
```

It works with `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello` and fails with `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/SOMENAME`, `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/SOMENAME/` and `localhost/Symfony/web/demo/hello/`

How do I make the routing work with and without a name and with and without a trailing slash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a default value like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/", defaults={"name" = "John"})
 * @Route("/hello/{name}", name="_demo_hello")
 * @Template()
 */
public function helloAction($name) { ... }
```

It's also important to know that **you can have more than one route on the same action**, so no need to duplicate actions.

See documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/controller.html And: [@Route Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

I think your solution should also work if you append a `/` after your route `/hello`.

Comment: ok that fixes the default issue. Tx! Perhaps I was reading the wrong version of the manual but I had understood that if the placeholder was in the route then the parameter was required.

Comment: Any thoughts about the trailing slash issue?

Comment: Just added it to my answer. You route is `/hello`, so, if you want that `/hello/` works, you have to append the `/` also to your route

Comment: Ah! I can have more than one route. Now I get it.  Thanks SO much!